# Querying several keywords separately but in a batch with SQL

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a list of 50 items and I want to extract some other data related to the from the my database (Postgres). One way is to write a simple `SELECT` statement and manually each time I replace the item. But I believe this is very dumb to do. Is this possible that I make this work in an automatic way? Is there a For loop or something in SQL with which I can do this?

Comment: `select * from table where field in (val1, val2, ..., valN)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `IN` construct facilitates selection on multiple values.

```
select * from MyTable where myfield in ( value1, value2, value3, value50 );
```

Comment: i have to join two table for this select. is this supported? or possible?

Comment: Just use a JOIN when you have to join.